# How do I install Zend Optimizer on an Amazon EC2 Linux AMI instance?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, zend-optimizer

I have been trying for days. I am stumped. Can someone help me? I got html and php installed.

But how do I get Zend Optimizer to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to install zend optimizer](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=6639&start=50) and  [here is ZendOptimizer.so for you (php 5.3)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3484507/ZendOptimizer.so)